# FFT 2D kernel runtime =0 in OpenCL

Tags: c++, vector, opencl, gpgpu

I’m working on a homework project compare performance of Fast Fourier Transform on CPU vs GPU . I’m done with the CPU part , but with GPU , I have a problem.

The trouble is the kernel runtime is zero , the input is the same as the output image . I use VS2010 on win7 with AMD APP SDK . Here is the host [**code**](http://pastebin.com/LXNPGd7V) , [**the kernel**](http://pastebin.com/SGrJuUac) , an addition **[header](http://pastebin.com/HcwtKhpS)** to handle the **[image](http://cosmin.users.sourceforge.net/testing/lena_16g_lin.pgm)**  ,  they can be found in The OpenCL Programming Book (Ryoji Tsuchiyama…)

My guess the error is in the phase where we pass values from the image pixels to the `cl_float2 *xm` (line 169-174 in the host code). I can’t access the vector component to check it either , the compiler ain’t accept `.sX` or `.xy` , throws an error about it . Other parts –kernel,header…- looks fine with me .

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {  
    for (j=0; j < n; j++) {  
        ((float*)xm)[(2*n*j)+2*i+0] = (float)ipgm.buf[n*j+i];   //real
        ((float*)xm)[(2*n*j)+2*i+1] = (float)0; //imag
    }   
}
```

So hope you guys help me out . Any ideas will be appreciated .

Comment: Please put all relevant code (and of course not more then that) in your question. If you can't puzzle that out at least format your code to be somewhat readable, because reading a buckload of badly indented code is not something many of us do enjoy.

Comment: Oh ; I'm sorry . I use Opera as the main browser and seems it ain't keep the format of the code :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCL provides a lot of different error codes.
You already retrieve them by doing `ret = clInstruction();` on each call, but you are not analysing it.

Please check on each call if this value is equal to `CL_SUCCESS`.
It may always happen, that the memory is not sufficient, the hardware is already in use or there is a simple error in your source code. The return value will tell you.

Also: Please check your `cl_context`, `cl_program`, etc. for `NULL` values.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion ; I'm on it . Seems it failed to load the kernel . 

I'll try to solve it out myself , then come back later for more detail . So I will vote for you later :)

Comment: Well ; I found a typo in the kernel , that why it ain't work .Thank you :D

Comment: My pleasure! :) (PS: You mean within the OpenCL-Code? Errors like this are directly shown in my shell when I do `clCreateProgramWithSource()`... weird.)

Comment: Yes , in the OpenCL code .  I get the log by `clGetProgramBuildInfo()` .

Comment: Ah, okay. I only have experience with the Intel SDK and another I can't name here ;) Both print the errors directly into the console, so I don't have to call any `clGetProgramBuildInfo` here. Good to know.